# gender identification in natural language processing

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I have written below code using stanford nlp packages.

```
GenderAnnotator myGenderAnnotation = new GenderAnnotator();
myGenderAnnotation.annotate(annotation);
```

But for the sentence "Annie goes to school", it is not able to identify the gender of Annie.

The output of application is:

```
     [Text=Annie CharacterOffsetBegin=0 CharacterOffsetEnd=5 PartOfSpeech=NNP Lemma=Annie NamedEntityTag=PERSON] 
     [Text=goes CharacterOffsetBegin=6 CharacterOffsetEnd=10 PartOfSpeech=VBZ Lemma=go NamedEntityTag=O] 
     [Text=to CharacterOffsetBegin=11 CharacterOffsetEnd=13 PartOfSpeech=TO Lemma=to NamedEntityTag=O] 
     [Text=school CharacterOffsetBegin=14 CharacterOffsetEnd=20 PartOfSpeech=NN Lemma=school NamedEntityTag=O] 
     [Text=. CharacterOffsetBegin=20 CharacterOffsetEnd=21 PartOfSpeech=. Lemma=. NamedEntityTag=O]
```

What is the correct approach to get the gender?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your named entity recognizer outputs `PERSON` for a token, you might use (or build if you don't have one) a gender classifier based on first names. As an example, see the [Gender Identification](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html) section from the NLTK library tutorial pages. They use the following features:

- Last letter of name.
- First letter of name.
- Length of name (number of characters).
- Character unigram presence (boolean whether a character is in the name).

Though, I have a hunch that using character n-gram frequency---possibly up to character trigrams---will give you pretty good results.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of approaches and one of them is outlined in [nltk cookbook](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html).

Basically you build a classifier that extract some features (first, last letter, first two, last two letters and so on) from a name and have a prediction based on these features.

```
import nltk
import random

def extract_features(name):
    name = name.lower()
    return {
        'last_char': name[-1],
        'last_two': name[-2:],
        'last_three': name[-3:],
        'first': name[0],
        'first2': name[:1]
    }

f_names = nltk.corpus.names.words('female.txt')
m_names = nltk.corpus.names.words('male.txt')

all_names = [(i, 'm') for i in m_names] + [(i, 'f') for i in f_names]
random.shuffle(all_names)

test_set = all_names[500:]
train_set= all_names[:500]

test_set_feat = [(extract_features(n), g) for n, g in test_set]
train_set_feat= [(extract_features(n), g) for n, g in train_set]

classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set_feat)

print nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_set_feat)
```

This basic test gives you approximately 77% of accuracy.

Comment: I put a '#' on each of the five features, eg: "#'last_char': name[-1],", so there shouldn't be any extracted feature, and running the code gives a 62-63% of accuracy, why is no feature predicting much better than a coin toss (50%)?

Comment: @KubiK888 the reason can be that a dataset is unbalanced (63% males) and after learning the NaiveBayes decided that the best way is to select males all the time.

Answer (score 1):

The gender annotator doesn't add the information to the text output but you can still access it through code as shown in the following snippet:

```java
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,parse,gender");

StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

Annotation document = new Annotation("Annie goes to school");

pipeline.annotate(document);

for (CoreMap sentence : document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
  for (CoreLabel token : sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)) {
    System.out.print(token.value());
    System.out.print(", Gender: ");
    System.out.println(token.get(MachineReadingAnnotations.GenderAnnotation.class));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Annie, Gender: FEMALE
goes, Gender: null
to, Gender: null
school, Gender: null
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the previous answer [@Sebastian Schuster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30335337/9292949) is some what close to the expected, it appears to be not working as for the current versions of Standford NLP

An updated and working example of that code segment is as below.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,parse,gender");

StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

Annotation document = new Annotation("Annie goes to school");

pipeline.annotate(document);

for (CoreMap sentence : document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
  for (CoreLabel token : sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)) {
    System.out.print(token.value());
    System.out.print(", Gender: ");
    System.out.println(token.get(CoreAnnotations.GenderAnnotation.class));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can add you two lectures more to nltk cookbook:

1. Gender Inference using Statistical Name Characteristics in Twitter (https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/2955129.2955182)
2. Damegender: Writing and Comparing Gender Detection Tools(http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-2754/paper3.pdf)

In the first lecture has been proposed several methods of feature selection being the next set as the start of discussion:

1. Number of syllables
2. Number of consonants
3. Number of vowels
4. Vowel brightness
5. Ending character

Using SVM, they speak about 70.9% of accuracy using namdict as main dataset.

In the second lecture, we have chosen the next feature selection:

1. contains a
2. last is a
3. last is o
4. last is consonant
5. last is vowel
6. 1st is consonant
7. 1st is vowel

Reaching an accuracy of 74.5% using as main dataset from this statistical institutions in these countries: Uruguay, Spain, United Kingdom, USA, Canada and Australia.